# Django - Geting fields by values_list in queryset

Tags: django, django-views

I have trouble getting values by values_list(From what I've read it is supposed to this) from my db in django:

```
stocks_query = Indexes.objects.filter(Symbol=index).values("Date","Open", "High", "Close", "Low","Volume")
print(stocks_query.values_list("Date", flat=True))
```

Every time I get QuerySet object

```
<QuerySet [datetime.date(2021, 12, 28), datetime.date(2021, 12, 27), datetime.date(2021, 12, 26), datetime.date(2021, 12, 24)...
```

Edit:
Thank you Willem, I understand now it more - if you want to see value you should iterate over it. (in my case I use pandas, so it was not necessary)
(for proper fields compatibility, I used pd.DatetimeIndex and pd.to_numeric))

Comment: What exactly do you *expect* as result?

Comment: A list of dates.

Comment: you can extract a list of dates with `list(stocks_query.values_list("Date", flat=True))`

Comment: Sorry, I mean I want extract pure dates - no dates objects

Comment: what are "pure" dates? Strings? In what format should these strings be?

Comment: yes, or pythonic datetime

Comment: the `date`s are from the `datetime` module.

Comment: My mistake, I later added this previous one (stocks_query.values_list("Date", flat=True)) to pandas dataframe and it worked fine. I was consufed with this "<QuerySet... " and types of fields  at the beginning beside of values itself.

Comment: yes, a `QuerySet` is iterable, hence pandas can iterate over it to obtain data, whether that data comes from a list, `QuerySet`, tuple, etc. is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can evaluate a `QuerySet` and convert the result to a list with:

```
list(stocks_query.values_list('Date', flat=True))
```

This will thus produce a `list` of `date` objects.

You can convert these for example to `YYYY-MM-DD`-formatted strings with:

```
list(map(str, stocks_query.values_list('Date', flat=True)))
```

or to `datetime` objects with:

```
from datetime import datetime

[datetime.fromordinal(d.toordinal()) for d in stocks_query.values_list('Date', flat=True)]
```